Two columns tables
EDIT
Hi, this is the compilable code. Sorry for haven't done it before.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=.3\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.7\hsize}X|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Actor(s)}  & 
        User\\ \hline
        \textbf{Event Flow}   & 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Item1
            \item Item2
        \end{enumerate}\\ \hline
        \textbf{Exceptions}  & 
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Item1
        \end{itemize}\\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}


The problem is that I don't want the that little third column.
I've specified just two of them and that's all what I desire.
If you have and idea, thanks a lot.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

That is not overflow (if you're referring to suc-cess) . That is normal hyphenation. Add \raggedright\arraybackslash is you just want ragged

Instead of reposting the same incomplete code fragment on yet another site, you could have taken this opportunity to make a small, but compilable example :(

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm new to Latex. Didn't think to post something immediately compilable. I'm sorry. Now, should be ok :)

You have two X columns, so the sum of the coefficients should be 2, not 1.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mpt}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  |
  >{\hsize=.6\hsize\mpt}X
  |
  >{\hsize=1.4\hsize\mpt}X
  |
}
\hline
\textbf{Actor(s)} &  User
\\
\hline
\textbf{Event Flow} & 
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Item1
    \item Item2
  \end{enumerate}
\\
\hline
\textbf{Exceptions} &
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Item1
  \end{itemize}
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}

I also added a trick to avoid unwanted space above enumerate and itemize. But you should really think whether you want a (caged) table.


You don't know but this is exactly what I was after. Also the unwanted space for enumerate anditemize! Thanks a lot!

You could use the tabularray package:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
      measure=vbox,
      colspec={X[.3,font=\bfseries]X[.7]},
      vlines,hlines,
      stretch=-1,
    }
        Actor(s)  & 
        User\\ 
        Event Flow   & 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Item1
            \item Item2
        \end{enumerate}\\
        Exceptions  & 
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Item1
        \end{itemize}\\ 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}


